# Gitを用いた開発環境の同期方法について

Tags: git, github

初めてGitを使っています。
家のPCと大学のPCからアクセスしながら開発したいと思ったのが理由です。家で作業して続きを大学でしたいと思った時、Google driveにアップしていたのですがより効率よく管理したいと思っています。Gitのコマンドなどはある程度わかるのですが、いまひとつ便利に使えていません。

知りたいのは、例えば、ローカルである程度作業した後、コミットしてリモートリポジトリにpushしてmergeするわけですが、作業の続きを大学でしたいわけですが、その時最新版を毎回cloneして作業しています。この時ローカルにある前回まで作業していたファイルなどが邪魔で削除しているのですが、これはこれで面倒な気がします。実際にGitを使っている人はcloneして持ってきた最新版に改良を加える際に、ローカルに残っているそれ以前のバージョンのファイルをどう処分していますか？

Comment: gitはファイル共有システムではありませんし（それっぽく使えますが）、やろうとされていることはGoogle Drive等で同期を取れば十分に思います。gitを使う目的、バージョン管理する必要性をご検討ください。

Comment: 十分ではないので使おうと考えています。

Answer (score 5):

毎回 `clone` する必要はありません。

`ブランチ`については理解している前提で記載をしますと
家で `push`したのであれば、
大学で
`fetch` して `merge`
または
`pull`
すれば、続きから再開できます。

Comment: 遅くなりましたがありがとうございます。

Comment: @はじめてgitマン 解決した場合は解決した回答に承認（チェック）を願いします。そうしないとい未解決の問題として残り続けてしまいます。

Answer (score 4):

`git clone`はこれからGitHubなどのリモートリポジトリとの同期を始める場合、もしくは最新版のファイルだけ取得したい場合に**初回だけ実行するコマンド**だと思ってください。

必要な同期の設定を行った後は、`git pull`や`git push`でローカルとリモートとの**差分**を同期していく形になります。

Comment: 遅くなりましたがありがとうございます。ようやく理解が深まりました。